# Trouble displaying variable in foreach loop using multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm able to display id and tags in the foreach loop no problem. But I'm having trouble showing title and height. I'm not sure how to call them into the foreach loop.

I can call them in the while loop so I know that they are working.

```
$persons = array();
$tags = array();

while( ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
{
    if(!isset( $persons[$row['id']]))
    {
        $persons[$row['id']]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $persons[$row['id']]['height'] = $row['height'];
        $persons[ $row['id'] ] = array( 'id' => $row['id'], 'tag' => $row['tag']);
        $tags[ $row['id'] ] = array();
    }
    $tags[ $row['id'] ][] = $row['tag'];
}

foreach( $persons as $pid => $p)
{
    echo 'id: # ' . $p['id'] ;
    echo 'title: ' . $p['title'];
    echo 'height: ' . $p['height'];
    echo '<a href="#">' . implode( '</a>, <a href="#">', $tags[ $p['id'] ])  . '</a>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting $persons[ $row['id'] ] when you set the tags, so you lost the other data.